# Возможно ли поддерживать ssh соединение при помощи хостинга и хотя бы видеть эту консоль?

Tags: bash, ssh, hosting, minecraft, виртуальная-машина

Итак, у меня на виртуальной машине, доступ к которой я получаю при помощи ssh, лежит Minecraft сервер.
Проблема заключается в том, что передо мной стоит выбор: либо постоянно иметь поднятый сервер без доступа к консоли и нормальному его отключению, либо сервер будет поднят до тех пор, пока я не закрою терминал.

Если я соединяюсь через терминал вручную, то все в порядке: доступ к консоли имеется, но стоит мне закрыть терминал - сервер падает(выключаю пк, к примеру). Другой вариант - включить его через скрипт, который устанавливает соединение и поднимает сервер. В таком случае можно даже выключить ПК, но сервер останется работать, но у меня более НИКОГДА не будет доступа к консоли, как я понимаю, пока я не перезагружу виртуальную машину и вновь не попытаюсь включить сервер.
Образный скрипт:

```
 ssh user@host -i key.key << EOF
 java -jar paper.jar -nogui 
 EOF
```

Возникает вопрос: можно ли как-то реализовать это по-другому, либо же иметь постоянный доступ к консоли? К примеру, через какой-нибудь хостинг сайтов...

Comment: `но у меня более НИКОГДА не будет доступа к консоли` используй screen / tmux.

Comment: Попробовал tmux. Да, теперь доступ к консоли действительно, однако сессия держится максимум 4 часа после выключения пк. ServerAliveInterval и ClientAliveInterval никак не спасают. Созданная скриптом сессия в то же время без каких-либо настроек держалась около 2 дней даже с выключенным ПК)

Comment: мультиплексор (screen/tmux/и т.п.) надо запускать не сервере. он будет работать пока не остановите (мультиплексор или сервер).

Comment: Понял, спасибо..